# Freeing void pointer causes segfault

Tags: c

I am getting a segfault when I free a void pointer...

I'm trying to make a dynamic and generic array, to store enemies in my game:

```c
typedef struct EnemyPool {
    void** elements;
    unsigned int element_count;
    unsigned int element_capacity;
    unsigned int element_size;
} EnemyPool;
```

It's an array of void pointers.

I create the array like so:

```c
pool->elements = malloc(pool->element_capacity * sizeof(void*));
```

And update like this:

```c
pool->element_capacity *= 2;
pool->elements = realloc(pool->elements, pool->element_capacity * sizeof(void*));
```

I create new elements like this:

```c
pool->elements[new_idx] = malloc(pool->element_size);
```

`pool->element_size` is correct, it's simply a `sizeof` to the type of element that this array is storing...

So why, when I do:

```c
free(pool->elements[0]);
```

I get a segfault...

I think it's freeing too much memory, since the segfault doesn't come from the `free` function, it comes from `glfwSwapBuffers`, but only after calling this particular `free` - A similar thing happened when I overflowed a buffer previously, which is why I think it's freeing too much memory. The question is why?

Comment: Try running your code through valgrind.  If you're mismanaging memory it will tell you where.

Comment: nothing wrong in what you've posted that I see, please post [mre]. Why the `void` pointers instead of a pointer to the type of element?

Comment: @dbush I ran it through Valgrind and I figured it out - it had nothing to do with how I am storing stuff.

Answer (score 2):

The segfault had absolutely nothing to do with that `free` or corrupt memory: I was trying to access the pointer right after calling the `free` on it... I figured this out using Valgrind, as suggested by a commenter. I didn't actually know Valgrind existed until today, that was really helpful.